# ⌘+Delete does not work in Firefox

Tags: keyboard, firefox

Firefox, for whatever reason, doesn't support the OS X-standard <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> shortcut for deleting the current line of text.

How do I get it back?

10.8 with FF22, but this behavior has been around for a while.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work for me either. You can use control-U to delete a complete line, but it also deletes the part on the right side of the caret.

Or if you use KeyRemap4MacBook, add something like this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<item>
  <name>firefoxcmddelete</name>
  <identifier>firefoxcmddelete</identifier>
  <only>FIREFOX</only>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::DELETE, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::DELETE</autogen>
</item>
```

Comment: How come you are not a Mod ? By choice ?

Comment: I'd note that Ctrl-U doesn't work on Stack Exchange answer boxes, because it is coded in the page as a shortcut to create an unordered list - as I discovered while trying to answer this last night :)

Comment: control-U does nothing at all in Firefox 25.0, iMac 10.8.3; it used to work, delete line, in ff 21.0. grrrrrr